# why incremental varible part of range not getting latest value?

Tags: python, python-2.7, range

Following piece of code, I expect range to vary every time when the flow increment +2. So I expect 0,8  2,8  4,6  6,8.
But it is following the linear increment like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 instead of 2,4,6,8

Code:

```
for i in range(i,count):
    i+=2
    print i
```

Output:

```
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
```

Comment: Either the loop sets `i` or you do.  If both, not so much.

Comment: The range is only calculate once

Comment: Syntax of range is (start, stop, step). In your case step is 2 but what about start and stop?

Comment: Python for loops do not work like C /Java for loops. They work like Java foreach loops.

Answer (score 0):

[Range in pydocs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range)

> The range type represents an immutable sequence of numbers and is commonly used for looping a specific number of times in for loops.

Which means that on every iteration your loop takes the next element from the list and the "+2" part gets dismissed. (overridden)

Answer (score 0):

i is reset on each iteration, use a different variable to increment, for instance:

```
j = 0
for i in range(i,count):
  j+=2
  print j
```

Answer (score 0):

`range` assigns the next value in the range to `i` in every iteration rendering  `i+=2` useless.

I would suggest you use

`for i in range(0,10,2):
  print(i)`